# Closable custom Lightning tabs in Salesforce

Tags: tabs, salesforce, lighting, aura-framework, lwc

Is it possible to create closable lightning:tab?

Following is the code snippet for lightning:tab but there is no out of box event/method to handle tab close operation.

```
<aura:component>
    <lightning:tabset selectedTabId="two">
        <lightning:tab label="Item One" id="one">
            One Content !
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Item Two" id="two">
            Two Content !
        </lightning:tab>
        <lightning:tab label="Item Three" id="three">
            Three Content !
        </lightning:tab>
    </lightning:tabset>
</aura:component>
```

Any help in making closable lightning tabs will be highly appreciated.

Note: I don't want to implement custom slds tabs because handling onactive event for custom slds tabs is a mess.